UE5: Live coding looking for files in old directory after moving project
While learning UE5, I had originally installed the program and my projects on my larger hard drive (J:) to avoid taking up space on my smaller SSD (C:). After beginning to use Live Coding, I found that my compile times were overly high and tried moving the project over to C:, the SSD, to speed the process up. Looking around online seemed to indicate that moving a project in UE5 should be as simple as moving the folder, and in most respects the transfer seemed to work - but when attempting to compile C++ files with Live Coding, the compiler fails. It seems to be looking for one of the files, 'ProjectName.patch_0.exe', in its old directory, with the error code LNK1104 and the exit code 0x450 once it checks the empty location.
Does anyone know how I could fix this?
The log file:
---------- Creating patch ----------
Running C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.2\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="DarkSouls4Editor Win64 Development -Project=""C:/Users/Shiloh/Documents/Unreal Projects/DarkSouls4/DarkSouls4.uproject""" -LiveCoding -LiveCodingModules="C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.2/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCodingModules.txt" -LiveCodingManifest="C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.2/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCoding.json" -WaitMutex -LiveCodingLimit=100
  Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
  Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -Target="DarkSouls4Editor Win64 Development -Project=""C:/Users/Shiloh/Documents/Unreal Projects/DarkSouls4/DarkSouls4.uproject""" -LiveCoding -LiveCodingModules="C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.2/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCodingModules.txt" -LiveCodingManifest="C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.2/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCoding.json" -WaitMutex -LiveCodingLimit=100
  Log file: C:\Users\Shiloh\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
  Invalidating makefile for DarkSouls4Editor (Item.cpp.obj.response modified)
  Building DarkSouls4Editor...
  Using Visual Studio 2022 14.40.33813 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
  [Upgrade]
  [Upgrade] Using backward-compatible include order. The latest version of UE has changed the order of includes, which may require code changes. The current setting is:
  [Upgrade]     IncludeOrderVersion = EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Unreal5_0
  [Upgrade] Suppress this message by setting 'IncludeOrderVersion = EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Unreal5_2;' in DarkSouls4Editor.Target.cs.
  [Upgrade] Alternatively you can set this to 'EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Latest' to always use the latest include order. This will potentially cause compile errors when integrating new versions of the engine.
  [Upgrade]
  Determining max actions to execute in parallel (6 physical cores, 12 logical cores)
    Executing up to 6 processes, one per physical core
    Requested 1.5 GB free memory per action, 3.19 GB available: limiting max parallel actions to 2
  Building 5 actions with 2 processes...
  [1/5] Compile [x64] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.InclOrderUnreal5_0.cpp
  Detected compiler newer than Visual Studio 2022, please update min version checking in WindowsPlatformCompilerSetup.h
  [2/5] Compile [x64] DarkSouls4.init.gen.cpp
  [3/5] Compile [x64] DarkSouls4.cpp
  [4/5] Compile [x64] Item.gen.cpp
  [5/5] Compile [x64] Item.cpp
  Total time in Parallel executor: 59.61 seconds
  Total execution time: 62.21 seconds
File C:\Users\Shiloh\Documents\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\DarkSouls4Editor\Development\Engine\SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.InclOrderUnreal5_0.h.obj was modified or is new
File C:\Users\Shiloh\Documents\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\DarkSouls4\DarkSouls4.cpp.obj was modified or is new
File C:\Users\Shiloh\Documents\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\DarkSouls4\DarkSouls4.init.gen.cpp.obj was modified or is new
File C:\Users\Shiloh\Documents\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\DarkSouls4\Item.cpp.obj was modified or is new
File C:\Users\Shiloh\Documents\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\DarkSouls4\Item.gen.cpp.obj was modified or is new
Building patch from 5 file(s) for Live coding module C:\Users\Shiloh\Documents\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Binaries\Win64\UnrealEditor-DarkSouls4.dll
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'J:\Unreal\Unreal Projects\DarkSouls4\Binaries\Win64\UnrealEditor-DarkSouls4.patch_0.exe'
Failed to link patch (0.000s) (Exit code: 0x450)```


Did you close and restart the Editor from the new directory after moving it?

Yes, I've restarted the editor a few times, including by launching directly from the .uproject file sitting in its new directory. But I haven't moved the UE5 installation itself (due to lack of space on my C drive), if that's what you mean - only the project file. The editor is still on my HDD, J:, for the moment.

Did you regenerate project files? Right-click .uproject and select Generate <IDE> Project Files.

That appears to have done the trick! Thank you so much!

The Visual Studio project files aren't automatically synchronized with the disk content and your solution still references the old folder.
To regenerate the solution with the current files, right-click on your .uproject and click on Generate Visual Studio project files.
This must be done to update the solution to the new/updated disk files.
